# "does not have a Release file" for Ubuntu 20.04 upgrading nginx via add-apt-repository

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, nginx

I'm trying to upgrade a server from nginx 1.18 to a supported mainline version.

`add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/mainline`

I keep seeing an error:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/mainline/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

From what I've seen online, people have been able to upgrade their nginx to 1.23+ on Ubuntu 20.04. I checked online docs / other questions and it seems like this is all I should need to do to upgrade nginx. Is there anything else I'm missing? I tried `apt-get update` and `apt update` as well; both completed successfully.

Comment: 3rd party sources are on you to check..   A quick look at https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/ubuntu/mainline before you added it would have told you the source was *unmaintained* and thus has no support for any current release of Ubuntu. Your release is *too modern* for that PPA.

Comment: I'll also suggest you apply security fixes asap to your system, as your provided details show you've not applied any for almost a year (see https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ though installed systems upgraded to 20.04.5 **before** that date, with the data representing the ISO release only) if not longer, and fully upgraded systems now report as 20.04.6  (*I hope you keep your system offline!*)

Answer (score 1):

The ppa you added to your system does not provide any packages for focal, you can not use this ppa, remove it from your system and use [this one](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/nginx-mainline?field.series_filter=focal) instead.